# How to create a initialization function with promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I need a initialization function called only one time for a module. This function is a promise and is called by an execute function. If execute is called twice, the second must wait the initialization then continue the execution.

I wrote this code, but the second call of execute is always waiting and doesn't never return. What have i missed?

```
var initialized = false;
var initializing = false;
var initializationPromise;

var init = function () {
    initializing = true;
    return q.promise(function (resolve) {
        // simulate initialization
        setTimeout(function () {
            // initialized
            initialized = true;
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    }).fin(function () {
        initializing = false;
    });
};
var execute = function () {
    return q.promise(function (resolve, reject, notify) {
        if (initialized) {
            // already initialized
            resolve();
        } else {
            if (!initializing) {
                // initializing
                initializationPromise = init().then(function () {
                    // simulate execution
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        resolve();
                    }, 1000);
                }, function (reason) {
                    reject(reason);
                });
            } else {
                // Wait : initializing in progress
                return initializationPromise;
            }
        }

    });
};

execute().then(function () {
    // This is executed
});
execute().then(function () {
    // This is never executed
});
```

Comment: By "*This function is a promise*" you mean "this function *returns* a promise"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> // Wait : initializing in progress
> return initializationPromise;
> ```

is not correct. That doesn't wait for anything, it just drops out of the `q.promise` constructor and does not do anything. Also you seem to employ the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it).

What you should do instead is

```
var initialisationPromise = null;
function isInitialised() {
    return initialisationPromise != null && initialisationPromise.isFulfilled();
}
function isInitialising() {
    return initialisationPromise != null && initialisationPromise.isPending();
}

function init() {
    // init can be called as often as necessary, and returns when it's done
    if (initialisationPromise == null) { // do the test here!
        // this part runs only once
        initialisationPromise = q.promise(function (resolve) {
            // simulate initialization
            setTimeout(function () {
                // initialized
                resolve();
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
    return initialisationPromise;
}
function execute() {
    return init().then(function () {
        return q.promise(function(resolve, reject, notify) {
            // simulate execution
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve();
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Where are we using `isInitialised` and `isInitialising` in the logic?

Comment: @Ultrablendz We're not, but it seemed the OP had some use for them. You can safely omit them if you don't need the status.

Answer (score 1):

A resolved/rejected promise will maintain its state (resolved or rejected state), so you can use it to run the initialization code only once. To do that, the `init()` function should return **always the same promise** and not create it every time.

For this reason, we create a deferred object (`initializationDeferred`) outside the `init()` method and use `initializationDeferred` to return **the same promise** every time `init()` method is called. We need, also, to check if the `init()` has been already done before, we use the shared variable `initializationStarted` to skip the `setTimeout` if already done in a previous invocation.

Now, inside `execute` you can be sure that the *onFulfilled* callback of `then()` is called only when `init()` method is initialized.

```js
var initializationDeferred = Q.defer(); // Create here the deferred object so it's common to all init() invocations
var initializationStarted = false;

var init = function() {
  if (!initializationStarted) {
    initializationStarted = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      // initialized
      console.log('Init timeout fired!');
      initializationDeferred.resolve(true); // Resolve the promise associated to the deferred object
    }, 1000);
  }

  return initializationDeferred.promise; // Return the promise associated to the deferred object
};

var execute = function() {

  return init().then(function(initialized) {
    // Here your module is initialized and you can do whatever you want
    // The value of "initialized" here is always "true"
    console.log('Execute: initialized?', initialized);
  });
};

execute().then(function() {
  // This is executed
  console.log('Execute First invocation');
});
execute().then(function() {
  // This is executed too
  console.log('Execute Second invocation');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/0.9.2/q.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, this will run the initialisation twice

Comment: I have updated the code. Check the console messages and you will see the init code is done only once.

Comment: Yes, that `initializationStarted` had been missing, thanks for the edit.